# Haskell pointless performance - efficiently map multiple functions to the same data

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pointfree

I often have to map multiple functions to the same data. I have implemented dpMap to do this for me

```
dpMap fns = (`map` fns) . flip ($)
```

dpMap is one function, does this mean I read the data dt just once (like a circuit fed with just the same input. A pointless system reminds of a circuit; just the plumbing no data)?

As an example consider calculating the minimum and maximum of a list dt.

```
minimax dt = (dpMap [minimum, maximum]) dt
```

*(I could get rid of the dt but have to use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction)*

Is there a performance advantage over implementing the same function in a point-full form like this?:

```
minimax2 dt = [minimum dt, maximum dt]
```

EDIT: Is there a general implementation of dpMap which works with constant memory?

I found another nice blog post: http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/08/composable-streaming-folds.html ;hope this helps.

<strike>EDIT2: After some more context, here is a solution, even though I don't have an exact implementation of dpMap, the pattern is simple enough that it doesn't warrant a separate function:</strike>

```
minimax = (,) <$> minimum <*> maximum
```

Usage:

```
> minimax [1..100]
(1,100)
```

If you want to also calculate the sum and the length

```
func = (,,,) <$> minimum <*> maximum <*> sum <*> length
```

Usage:

```
> func [1..100]
(1,100,5050,100)
```

Comment: It's pointless because both versions will go over the list twice. Use fold to get min/max in one go.

Comment: another pointless definition: `dpMap fns = (fns <*>) . pure`.

Comment: n.b. `dpMap = sequence` (though with a specialised type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to take a fairly broad view of the question in this answer, mostly because of the comments under WillNess's answer.

In a [blog post](http://squing.blogspot.sg/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html), Max Rabkin introduced some work on folding combinators.  Conal Elliott picked up this idea and published a few more blog posts as well as the [ZipFold package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ZipFold) on hackage.  I would highly recommend reading this material, it's short and pretty accessible.  The ZipFold package is probably very usable, although it hasn't been updated for some time.

Edward Kmett's recent tour-de-force, `lens`, also includes some [folding combinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-Fold.html).  I'm not sure I'd want to use it just for that, but if you're using lens anyway it's probably worth looking in to.

An alternative approach is to use parallelism.  If you write

```
import Control.Parallel

minimax2 dt = let a = minimum dt
                  b = maximum dt
              in a `par` b `pseq` [a,b]
```

and link with -threaded, then it's possible for `minimax2` to run in something close to constant space, depending on the vagaries of the scheduler, phases of the moon, etc (mostly the scheduler and allocation patterns of the functions IIRC).  Of course this doesn't provide reliable guarantees, but it can work well in practice.  Generalizing this approach to `dpMap` should be straightforward, you'd probably want to use `Control.Parallel.Strategies` or similar rather than using the lower-level `par` directly.

Finally, most of the iteratee-derived libraries are quite good at handling this sort of task.  In general they provide explicit control over when input streams are produced and consumed.  In `iteratee` I provide [sequence_](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/iteratee/0.8.9.4/doc/html/Data-Iteratee-ListLike.html#v%3asequence_) which does almost the same as `dpMap`, will be adding `sequence` which will do exactly the same thing as `dpMap`, and a number of zips, all of which run in constant space (provided that the consuming functions are themselves constant-space).  I wouldn't be surprised if most of the other packages provided similar operations.

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR**: There are no guarantees about performance in the language itself. None whatsoever. It is a *compiler* thing.

As the rule of thumb, a *named* entity will be memory resident. If it is accessed *lazily* by only one consumer, it is reasonable to expect it to be optimized such that the compiled program will run in constant memory.

The creation and consumption of memory cells will be interleaved, and each cell will be GC-ed after it was processed.

---

In `minimax2 dt = [minimum dt, maximum dt]`, the expression `[minimum dt, maximum dt]` is inside the scope where the named entity `dt` is defined. Most probably (i.e. almost certain) that  GHC will allocate it as a memory entity, i.e.  once, and both `dt` inside the expression will refer to the same entity (point to it, as if pointers).

But as Cat Plus Plus points out in the comments, of course how is entity is accessed is quite another matter. And the two sub-expressions will each access it separately, i.e. it will be retained in memory in full. That's no good.

We can do better, and find our answer by accessing it only once, with a fold, collecting the two pieces of data as we go along. In such situation, it is almost certain that GHC will perform an optimization where this list will *not* be retained in memory as a whole.

This is what is usually refered to as the list being consumed *lazily*. When that's the case, its creation will be interleaved with that one access, and each memory cell produced will be immediately consumed and released, by GC (garbage collection), so that constant memory operation will be achieved.

But that's predicated on our ability to scan through the list only *once*:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 -XBangPatterns #-}

import Data.List (foldl')

minmax :: (Ord b) => [b] -> (b, b)
minmax (x:xs) = foldl' (\(!a,!b) x -> (min a x,max b x)) (x,x) xs
```

Bang patterns prevent thunk build-up, making evaluation of arguments more eager. Testing:

```
Prelude> minmax [1..6]
(1,6)
Prelude> minmax []
*** Exception: <interactive>:1:4-65: Non-exhaustive patterns in function minmax
```

An empty list of course has no minimum nor maximum defined.

For the optimizations to kick in, `-O2` flag must be used when compiling with GHC.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :-). One problem with this approach is that everytime I need to perform multiple set of operations on the same data, I'll need to define a new variant of fold. Is there a general implementation of dpMap ? P.S: I'm still wrapping my head around the suggestions in the comments.

Comment: @GeneralBecos why *new* fold? Old foldl'! (or foldr, whatever's appropriate). Don't mind the comments, it's a sport here to find the most short - and *incomprehensible* - rendition of a given function. :) :) Of course YMMV, and `sequence` may actually make sense. :) (it has to do with Monads, and `<*>` version with Applicatives). Use the implementation as here, in the answer. It tries to be efficient, and that's a good thing. Constant memory operation (i.e. when memory consumption doesn't grow as program runs) is something to strive for.

Comment: @GeneralBecos that's a good question btw, you could ask a new question - how to generalize this approach. i.e. havng a list of functions, how to achieve one-pass operations. ask it - the new question I mean. :)

Comment: That was actually my original intent. I phrased it poorly. I have updated the question with my intuition of the point less style.

Comment: @GeneralBecos well OK, let's see if there will be any takers. this answer is already too long. :)